# Send the requested ID to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, sql-delete

JS FILE

```
buttons: {
               save : function() {
                  calEvent.id = id;
                  id++;
                  calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
                  calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
                  calEvent.title = titleField.val();
                  calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

                  //post to events.php
                  $.post("events.php?action=save&start="+calEvent.start.getTime()/1000+"&end="+calEvent.end.getTime()/1000+"&title="+calEvent.title+"&body="+calEvent.body);

                  $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
                  $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
                  $dialogContent.dialog("close");
               },,
            "delete"  : function() {
                  calEvent.id = id;
                  id++;

                  //post to events.php
                 $.post( "events.php", { action: "del", id: calEvent.id });

                  $calendar.weekCalendar("removeEvent", calEvent.id);
                  $dialogContent.dialog("close");


                } ,
               cancel : function() {
                  $dialogContent.dialog("close");
               }
            }
         }).show();
```

PHP FILE

```
if ($action == 'del')
{
    $id = $_GET['id']; 

    $del = "DELETE FROM meeting_rooms_calendar WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($del, $link);
    print_r($id);
} 
elseif($action == 'save')
{
    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];
    $start_time = (int)$_REQUEST['start'];
    $start_time = $start_time + 60*60;
    $end_time = (int)$_REQUEST['end'];
    $end_time = $end_time + 60*60;
    $start = date('c',$start_time);
    $end = date('c',$end_time);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO meeting_rooms_calendar(title,body,start,end) VALUES ('$title','$body','$start','$end')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

}
```

Now if I click save, save will post the request variables to PHP and PHP to the database, when I click DELETE it doesn't send the requested ID to PHP so PHP can't delete it from database how can I make the JS file send the ID to PHP.

If I do it manually by

```
www.myweb.com/events.php?action=del&id=1
```

This will delete it from database, so that means PHP works.
It's just the JS part, it don't delete it automatically from database.

Comment: Be careful, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection in multiple places. You should use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead of the deprecated `mysql_*`.

Comment: `$.post("events.php?action=save` you are posting to this page, but in fact you are sanding 'save' as part of the get parameter, where `del` later you are sending via real post

Comment: The code above is the save function that must call the action=save, but the other is delete function and that must call action=del

Answer (score 1):

You need use `$_POST` instead of `$id = $_GET['id']`;  since you are using jquery `$.post` method

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
```

Comment: still not working is it sending from JS the ID to PHP ?
If i change it in POST it wont even delete from database manually
`events.php?action=del&id=46`

Comment: Did you added $action = $_POST['action'];?

Answer (score 0):

You are issuing a `$.post` via JS, but your rely on `$_GET` on your PHP code. Stick to `$_POST`.

Comment: still not working is it sending from JS the ID to PHP ?
If i change it in POST it wont even delete from database manually
`events.php?action=del&id=46`

Comment: Use `$_REQUEST` then. But better make a fair use of HTTP protocol and stick to RESTful standards [ie. `DELETE  /resource/:id`]instead of RPC fashion [i.e. `?action=delete&id=:id`].